# Lifetime of the object returned by std::string::substr

Tags: c++, string, c++11, lifetime, temporary

I need to know whether the following is valid in general.

```
string s = "some value";
string v = s.substr(0, 50).c_str();
```

Is the assignment to `v` always valid? Can there be any issues due to the temporary lifetime of object returned by `substr()`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's valid here. The [temporary](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lifetime) returned by `substr` is destroyed after the full expression; which includes the initialization of `v`.

> All temporary objects are destroyed as the last step in evaluating the full-expression that (lexically) contains the point where they were created, and if multiple temporary objects were created, they are destroyed in the order opposite to the order of creation. This is true even if that evaluation ends in throwing an exception.

<sup>BTW: This is not assignment but initialization (construction) of `v`.</sup>

Answer (score 4):

The assignment to `v` is valid. Temporary objects are not destroyed until the end of the whole statement is finished (when the `;` is reached), which is after the assignment is complete.

However, in this particular example, the use of `c_str()` is redundant and inefficient. It requires iterating the `char` data to determine its length, which the temp `string` returned by `substr()` already knows, so just assign the returned `string` as-is:

```
string v = s.substr(0, 50);
```

Comment: Yes, but `s/assign/initialise/`. Also this way you avoid an unnecessary copy of the buffer which I'd say is the main benefit

Answer (score 0):

> [substr](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/substr/) returns a newly constructed string object with its value
>   initialized to a copy of a substring of this object.

So you are safe

Answer (score -2):

> Once you've assigned a variable, it is under the protection of the
>   scope of the variable. It will not change till you change it, or it
>   loses scope, as I said. There is only a "temporary lifetime" if you
>   have the instantiation nested.

My own quote above. All you're asking about is "How or when does the .substr function look in the memory for it, and does it stay in memory?" The answer is its copy is in the assignment to the left value. Considering that, the .substr function's action on the memory is lost. So yes it is temporary. But as I vaguely asserted already, that is temporal to the scope of the variable.

Comment: the result of `.substr` has temporary lifetime, which is rather the point

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Hows this?

Comment: Still missing the complexities of extracting an "unmanaged" pointer from a temporary then using it to initialise something. The result of `substr()` is _not_ copied to the left value, at least not directly.

Comment: Adding this level of the machine logic I think expresses too much for a question this subtle. Or maybe I'm wrong. But the 'value' is now in two intrinsic places. This debate over it being a copy will go nowhere, however. I'm sure you've knowledge of it more than I. But the idea of 2 of 1 is a copy to me. However it was instantiated. I understand the machine logic though, at this point. I think I'll just press for the understanding to be thought of without culling the confusion of the topic without standard documentation. @LightnessRacesinOrbit

Comment: No, that's literally the point of the question, and has nothing to do with machine logic. The OP was wondering whether the `substr()` result temporary lives long enough for the `c_str()` to remain valid long enough to initialise `v`. (Fortunately, it does, due to rules set out in the standard about when the temporaries are destroyed.) You didn't address any of that.